# Turn mysql database to pdo class in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, frameworks

I have a data table and i want to create pdo class to manipulate with it and turn fields of data table to public variables where i can access to them.

Exemple:

```
<?php 
 class personne
  {
      //code to get fields from datatable and turn them to variables
  }

 $p=personne::find(1); //find personne who have 1 as id
 echo $p->nom;
?>
```

and the value of the fields stocked in value of variables

thanks.

Comment: Okay... Is there any questions? Any issues you have encountered?

Comment: If `find` is a static method of `personne`, you musn't use `new`. `$p=new personne::find(1);` gives an error anyway

Comment: yes i agree with you Clément i edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
class Person {

  private static $instance = null;
  private $db;
  private static $data;

  private function __construct() {
    try {
      $pdo_param = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
      );
      $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=YOUR_HOST_NAME;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME", "YOUR_USERNAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD", $pdo_param);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

  private static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance == null) {
      self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public static function find($id) {
    try {
      $instance = self::getInstance();
      $result = $instance->db->query(YOUR_SQL_QUERY);
      self::$data = (object)$result->fetch();
      return self::$data;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

}

$p = Person::find(1);
echo $p->name;
```

Comment: sorry not working it give this "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/touhfata/new/p/index.php on line 31"

Comment: Fixed it, and tested it as well. It should work now.

Comment: This way of doing it is called Singleton Design Pattern, which is often used in database connection classes, to make sure that there's only 1 instance of the class.